# Is there a way to reach default operator function in overloaded operator function?

Tags: c++

I want to wrap an operator function with overloading it for debug purposes.

E.g: I want to count how many = operation have been done during a program run for Foo object.

```
static int counter = 0;
Foo operator=(const Foo& b) 
{
    //Somehow call default functionality of = opreator for foo.

    counter++;
}
```

Is it possible to call just default functionality of operators when overloading them. Just like calling base function of overridden function when writing an overridden function.

Comment: What you need is a [CRTP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) class which counts assignments. I cannot provide you with the code right now, but this should be fairly easy...

Comment: I have tested a way. But it requires that your copy ctor exactly what copy assignment operator does (except counter++).

Answer (score 3):

If by "default operator function" you mean you want the `operator=()` to do everything that would be achieved if you simply did

```
Foo &operator=(const Foo &) = default;
```

but, in addition, increment a counter, then there is no direct way, since such an operator can only have one definition.

However, you can achieve a similar effect by using something like

```
class Counter
{
     public:

          Counter &operator=(const Counter &) {++counter; return *this;};

          static int Count() {return counter;};
     private:
          static int counter;
};
```

and (in exactly one compilation unit that has visibility of the definition of class `Counter`  e.g. by including the header that contains the class definition) do

```
int Counter::counter = 0;
```

Then simply add a single `Counter` as a private non-static member of your class `Foo`.   That way, every usage of a "defaulted" `operator=()` in class `Foo` will increment the `Counter::counter`.

If your class `Foo` is the only place that a `Counter` is used, then the above will allow counting the number of times a `Foo` is assigned.   All you need to do to obtain the count, at any time, is call `Counter::Count()`.

As noted by Caleth in comments, the class `Counter` can be templated on the type, so a distinct counter for `Foo` versus other classes can be established.   This also opens the door for using CRTP (the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern) in which `Foo` can derived from `Counter<Foo>` to provide the desired capability.

There are some potential caveats to be aware of;

- The size of a `Counter` will be non-zero, so the size of a `Foo` will probably change.
- You will need to ensure constructors and destructor of class `Counter`
  (however they are defined) work correctly with `Foo`;
- The behaviour will be undefined if `Counter::count` ever overflows
  (which caps the number of times your class can be assigned);
- There is nothing to stop other code from instantiating and assigning
  a `Count`, which will mess up your count   (although that possibility
  might be mitigated  (note I didn't say "countered") if `Counter` has all members `private` and  specifies class `Foo` as a `friend`).

Comment: You can template `Counter` on a type, so that `Counter<Foo>` has a distinct count to `Counter<Bar>`

Comment: It seems there is no way to do that I want. But, I liked the approach and it will be very useful in some cases I think. Thanks.

Comment: @Caleth - yes, that's true.   When I think about it a bit more, it could be used as a base class as well (i.e. a form of CRTP) since the "default" `operator=()` for a class will take care of calling `operator=()` for bases.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide a custom `operator=` implementation, the compiler doesn't generate the default one. There is no way to access it because it doesn't exist.

I suggest making a separate class with overloaded `operator=`, and adding it to `class Foo` as a field (or a base class).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that introduces a template-based assignment operator, which will not overload the default one:

```
static int counter;
struct Foo
{
    template<bool=false> Foo& operator=(const Foo& b)
    {
        // The non-debug one
        return operator=(b);
    }
    template<> Foo& operator=<true>(const Foo& b)
    {
        // The debug one
        ++counter;
        return operator=(b);
    }
};
```

Then you can use

```
Foo f;
Foo g;
g.operator=<>(f); // This is the non-debug one
g.operator=<true>(f); // This is the non-debug one
g.operator=<false>(f); // This is the debug one
```

You can of course still write `g = f`.

Unfortunately though you can't, at the time of writing, write `g=<false>f;`, so the envisaged calling syntax is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Note : This will work only if copy constructor does exactly what copy assignment operator is supposed to do (except incrementing static counter).

```
Foo operator=(const Foo& b) 
{
    ++counter;

    //Somehow call default functionality of = opreator for foo.
    Foo copy(b);
    return copy;

    //counter++;
}
```

You can check my code at [onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/rkBRca_eB).

I am not sure of other pitfalls in using this, than the one mentioned at top. Criticism is most welcome.